# Inode Data Structure Differences Between 128-byte Ext2 and 256-byte Ext3

Tags: linux, filesystems, inode, ext3, ext2

Curious as to the inode data structure differences between 128-byte ext2 and 256-byte ext3 file-systems.

I have been using this reference for ext2, 128-byte inodes: http://www.nongnu.org/ext2-doc/ext2.html#INODE-TABLE.

I have been unable to find a similar resource for ext3, 256-byte inodes. I have cursorily checked /usr/include/linux/ext2_fs.h but it seems to only include definitions for ext2.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be wrong,but here is my guess. In ext3 256 byte is an optional one. On my ext3 system inode 128 bytes.If you need expert answer, better drop a mail to ext3-user list.Sure they will help you.